# Loose data on refresh page Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, pagination

I have an AngularJS  app like this one:

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview&preview

and the $scope data that I have, is from an API,

When the page first loaded I call to this API and I save the data that returned in the session,

Now I can't understand why when I refresh the page I Losing information and all the data,

How can I use the data dynamic that when I refresh the page I don't loos data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you using routing in your app? Here is simple example :
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Svg4Po13hMq7WxzNwKDc?p=preview&preview
With routing you do not need to refresh your page.

As to the problem itself (don't loss data after refresh):

- if you want to keep your data even when you refresh your browser use localStorage. There're lots of handy localStorage angularJS modules to use - ex. 
  https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage
- if you don't want to store data on the client side, you could request your API for the data you need to store each time your angular app is getting loaded. This data seems to be static, as you are storing it on client side and reuse then, so you could configure API endpoint to throw this data really fast.